# Highchart axis 2 decimal places

Tags: highcharts, formatting, decimal

I have a question about formatting my axis on highcharts. I want to display the ticks on the Y axis in decimals with 2 decimal places.

The current situation:

- 0
- 0.05
- 0.1
- 0.15
- 0.2

I want to display my number like this:

- 0.00
- 0.05
- 0.10
- 0.15
- 0.20

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

-->[API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.format)

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value:.2f}'
    }
}
```